# TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined error while trying to make a command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was trying to make a command to ping a random user each time the command is run but I seem to have run into a problem.

Here's my code:

```js
const DiscordCommand = require('../../contracts/DiscordCommand');
class KickCommand extends DiscordCommand {
  onCommand(message) {
    message.delete();
    const userList = message.guild.members.cache.array();
    var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * message.guild.memberCount);
    var pingPerson = userList[randomNumber];
    message.channel.send('<@' + pingPerson.user.id + '>').then((msg) => {
      msg.delete({ timeout: 100 });
    });
  }
}

module.exports = KickCommand;
```

The error I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
```

Comment: I do not know the actual issue, but `Math.round(Math.random() * message.guild.memberCount)` can return you one index too high. If you have two users you can get a number between 0 and 2 due to the count being 2, whereas the array only holds index 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Math.round(Math.random() * message.guild.memberCount)` can return numbers larger than than the last index as you use [`round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) instead of [`floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).

However; instead of creating a random generator function, you could use [`Collection#random()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=random) to obtain unique random value(s) from a collection.

`message.guild.members.cache` returns a collection, so you could use it like this:

```js
class KickCommand extends DiscordCommand {
  onCommand(message) {
    message.delete();
    const pingPerson = message.guild.members.cache.random();
    message.channel.send('<@' + pingPerson.user.id + '>').then((msg) => {
      msg.delete({ timeout: 100 });
    });
  }
}
```

It's probably also a good idea to `fetch` the users first:

```js
class KickCommand extends DiscordCommand {
  async onCommand(message) {
    message.delete();
    await message.guild.members.fetch();
    
    const pingPerson = message.guild.members.cache.random();
    const msg = await message.channel.send('<@' + pingPerson.user.id + '>');

    // msg.delete() doesn't take any parameters in v13, so use setTimeout instead
    setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 100);
  }
}
```

And make sure that the `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent is enabled.

Comment: Another question, how can I make the message send it to a particular channel w/ the channel id?

Comment: You can fetch the channel (e.g. `const channel = await client.channels.fetch(channelID)` or `const channel = await message.guild.channels.fetch(channelID)`) and use `channel.send` instead of `message.channel.send`.